# JS module "YAML" does not stringify with quotes in the documented format

Tags: javascript, yaml

I have a client that needs YAML output in a specific way for a legacy app. The format they need in the file is

```
key: "string"
key: 123
```

[According to the docs](https://eemeli.org/yaml/#scalar-options) for the `YAML` module (recommended on https://yaml.org/):

```
YAML.scalarOptions.str.defaultType = 'QUOTE_SINGLE'
YAML.stringify({ this: null, that: 'value' })
```

Which reads as if using the `defaultType` option `'QUOTE_SINGLE'` will format the element as `that: 'value'`.

It does not. What it does is format the entry like `'that': 'value'`, and the option `'QUOTE_DOUBLE'` sets it to `"that": "value"`.

[edit] I even tried adding `YAML.scalarOptions.str.defaultKeyType = 'PLAIN'` which had no visible effect on the output.

I'm not sure if I've missed a config setting somewhere, or if it's a bug.

What options for the YAML module do I need to use in order to set string-values in double quotes, but leave string-keys without quotes?

Comment: While the documentation seems to be wrong, you could still try explicitly setting `str.defaultKeyType` to `'PLAIN'` (described as the default value in the docs) and see if that fixes it.

Comment: @flyx I actually tried that to no effect. Will change the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question.

I wasn't the one that installed the module. I believe the person did a simple `yarn add yaml`.

By default it installed version 1.2.

The website for the module, by default, shows documentation for version 2.0.